# IE8 problems when using jquery text() method for parsing XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to parse an XML file with the following XML format:

```
<mainTag>
    <tag1>1</tag1>
    <tag2>2</tag2>
    <tag3>3</tag3>
    <tag4>4</tag4>
    <tag5>5</tag5>
    <tag6>6</tag6>
    <tag7>7</tag7>
</mainTag>
```

I'm using the javascript/jquery code below to do so (relevant part shown; xml is the data that results from the AJAX call):

```
$(xml).find("mainTag").each(function() {

    var constVal = $(this).text();

});
```

The issue that I'm running into is that when using IE8, `constVal` results in:

```
1234567
```

In other browsers (IE9+, FF, Chrome) the value for `constVa`l properly iterates through and gives:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Is there a way to stop IE8 from ignoring the newline characters and whitespace/preserve them?  Or a reasonable workaround? Editing the file is not an option.

Comment: Why not iterate the children tags instead, and add the newline yourself ?

Comment: weird. the result you get from IE 8 is the result i would expect. Did you set your dataType to xml, or parse it as xml in the success?

Comment: adeneo your solution worked.  I iterated over the .children() array.  Can't believe I didn't spot this solution myself. Thank you so much for your help!